# How to get a B2CUser from a IAuthenticationResult when using MSAL in Android

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL with Android in B2C multiuser mode. The code I am following is from [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp) example. It shows how to get a list of B2CUsers from a list of accounts:

```
private void loadAccounts() {
    if (b2cApp == null) {
        return;
    }

    b2cApp.getAccounts(new IPublicClientApplication.LoadAccountsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(final List<IAccount> result) {
            users = B2CUser.getB2CUsersFromAccountList(result);
            updateUI(users);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(MsalException exception) {
            displayError(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

But I also need to get the specific B2CUser after authenticating:

```
            AcquireTokenParameters parameters = new AcquireTokenParameters.Builder()
                    .startAuthorizationFromActivity(getActivity())
                    .fromAuthority(B2CConfiguration.getAuthorityFromPolicyName(policyListSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                    .withScopes(B2CConfiguration.getScopes())
                    .withPrompt(Prompt.LOGIN)
                    .withCallback(getAuthInteractiveCallback())
                    .build();

            b2cApp.acquireToken(parameters);
```

Which gives me a IAccount after from the authenticationResult:

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
            /* Successfully got a token, use it to call a protected resource - MSGraph */
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully authenticated");

            /* display result info */
            displayResult(authenticationResult);

            /* Reload account asynchronously to get the up-to-date list. */
            loadAccounts();
        }
```

But I can't seem to turn that into a B2CUser or get the ID from it as the:

```
iAuthenticationResult.getAccount().getId()
```

seems to return the policy appended to it and I cannot get the displayName either.

Comment: Thanks @ICj. Could you please share the graph API called from your code or use this sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java#b2cmodefragment-class

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/f3627771277e9e61d2058c0496f5c732706fd10c/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp/B2CModeFragment.java#L206 is where the list of users is turned into a `List<B2CUser>`. You can e.g. pick the first of these.